# Link to app in Android Market using Phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, html, cordova

I would like to link to a full version of my application using a link in the free version of my application that I have built using phonegap and jquery mobile.

I've tried just putting the URL in an href tag but this page loads for around 5 seconds then goes to a blank white page.

Am I missing something?

I'm using `<a href="http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.stackoverflow">click here</a>`

I've also tried

```
market://details?id=com.android.example
```

Comment: need to do the exact thing..  :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this by adding a rel="external" parameter to the a href tag.

```
<a href="http://market.android.com/details?id=com.example.name" rel="external">Press here</a>
```

Comment: ya... but how to call from JavaScript

Comment: Belated @AamirShah: use `window.open('http://market.android.com...', '_system');`

Comment: Don't forget that these need to be whitelisted - whether via <allow-intent> tags or CSP.